# Using Python to insert Excel DATE (not datetime) data into a SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x

I am trying to use Python to import Excel workbook data into SQL Server, but under the `TERM_DATE` column when I tried to import the values it said it was incompatible with float datatype.

What the column looks like in Excel:

```
TERM_DATE
43101
43101
43101
43101
43132
```

What I need the SQL Server column to look like

```
TERM_DATE
2018-01-01
2018-01-01
2018-01-01
2018-01-01
2018-02-01
```

**Extra info:**

`TERM_DATE` is a column within the table I created is a `date` datatype inside SQL Server; and when I use Python to try to import the `TERM_DATE` column from Excel to SQL Server, I get this error:

> DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Operand type clash: float is incompatible with date (206) (SQLExecDirectW); [22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')

Comment: Excel will display 43101 as 2018-01-1, but what's actually in the cell is 43101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shenanagans of converting `float` to and from `datetime` is not allowed for the newer `date` and `datetime2` colums.  Both SQL Server `datetime` and Excel dates are stored internally as floats, but Excel's "zero date" is 1900-01-00, while SQL Server uses 1900-01-01, and Excel has a bug where it treats 1900 as a leap year.

So if you subtract 2 from the Excel number, and then convert to a `datetime` then to a `date` you should get the same value.

eg something like:

```
insert into T(id, date) values (?, cast(?-2 as datetime))
```

Comment: Plus one for typing faster than me, plus I'll throw in the link I was going to include for some interesting further reading on Excel date weirdness. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm